# Got this at the sale where I got the combination plane. What is it?

Tags: wood, antique

This antique tool is wood. It has precise measurements marked to 3 inches, an adjustable depth gauge. Short pins that stick out along the measuring area. Is it used for masonry?
[image]

Comment: Would think more for marking wood.  Masonry is hard on wood, especially if dragged along it, as in marking.  Those two pins might be use for making lines(cut) in wood.

Comment: A picture of the bottom (from this perspective) would be most helpful. Also, pics showing what the thumb-screw on the left does would be useful. One would presume the thumb-screw closest to the camera locks the sliding ring to the rest of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a [marking gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marking_gauge) - specifically a mortise marking gauge.  It's used to scratch lines into wood parallel to an edge.  The block is adjustable to change the distance from the edge to one of the pins.  The other pin is independently adjustable to change the distance between them.  When making mortises it marks both edges of the mortise with a single step.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.